# Is there a way of determining the "defined" vs. "computed" style property of an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to determine if an absolutely-positioned element's size is being determined by positioning or dimension.

E.g. an element with a `left` and `width` will have a *computed* `right` but `getComputedStyle` will simply report all three values. I want to be able to distinguish between an element whose `width` is computed from `left` and `right` vs. one whose `width` is defined, etc.

Now, I know that I can "experimentally" change a property, use getComputedStyle to see if something changes, and then restore the property, without the user seeing a "flicker" so this is one option.

E.g. if I want to see if an object's `width` is defined I can try changing `left` and `right` independently to see whether changing on of them does not change computed `width` (in which case `width` is defined, but even this won't tell me if the width is a result of the element's content vs. a css rule

Comment: Can you not just read the style value and determine the answer with javascript? `elem.style.right` would be empty if not assigned

Comment: inspect the element in devtools?

Comment: @SpencerMay reading the style attribute won't tell you what has been set thro' a stylesheet.

Comment: @AHaworth is exactly right. Basically I'm looking for something that is like `getComputedStyle()` but returns only explicitly set values (from anywhere) and not computed values.

Comment: @James you can get this information (with difficulty) from the CSS inspector, but the whole point is to surface this information in an actual user interface.